# Pass variables from Scala to Python in Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using Databricks and trying to pass a dataframe from Scala to Python, within the same Scala notebook. I passed a dataframe from Python to Spark using:

```
%python
python_df.registerTempTable("temp_table")


val scalaDF = table("temp_table")
```

How do I do that same thing in reverse? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reverse will pretty much the same. In Scala:

```scala
scalaDF.registerTempTable("some_table")
```

In Python:

```py
spark.table("some_table")
```

If you use recent Spark version you should use `createOrReplaceTempView` in place of `registerTempTable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the .createOrReplaceTempView() method or sql().

Here is an example to pass a dataframe through from scala, python, onto sql with a modification along the way ...and back to scala.

```
%scala 
var df = spark.range(0,10).selectExpr("*","'scala' language_origin")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tableName")
display(df)

%python
df = sql("select * from tableName")
df2 = df.selectExpr("*","'python' language_added")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tableName")
display(df2)

%sql
create or replace temp view tableName as
select *, 'sql' language_added from tableName;
select * from tableName

%scala
df = sql("select * from tableName")
display(df)
```

Comment: Why not use `pipe` to send data to python and back? Is this more efficient?