# Using Python variable in scala cell

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, databricks

I have the below command in databricks notebook which is in python.

```py
batdf = spark.sql(f"""select cast((from_unixtime((timestamp/1000), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as date) as event_date,(from_unixtime((timestamp/1000), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as event_datetime, * from testable  """)
    
srcRecCount = batdf.count()
```

I have one more cell in the same notebook which is in scala as below.

```scala
%scala
import java.time._
var srcRecCount: Long = 99999
val endPart = LocalDateTime.now()
val endPartDelta =  endPart.toString.substring(0,19)
dbutils.notebook.exit(s"""{'date':'$endPartDelta', 'srcRecCount':'$srcRecCount'}""")
```

I want to access the variable `srcRecCount`  from python cell into scala cell in databricks notebook. Could you please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variables from Scala to Python in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884823/pass-variables-from-scala-to-python-in-databricks)

Comment: @SzymonKocot unfortunately, no

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can pass data via Spark configuration using `spark.conf.set` & `spark.conf.get`, like this:

```py
# Python part
srcRecCount = batdf.count()
spark.conf.set("mydata.srcRecCount", str(srcRecCount))
```

and

```
// Scala part
val srcRecCount = spark.conf.get("mydata.srcRecCount")
dbutils.notebook.exit(
  s"""{'date':'$endPartDelta', 'srcRecCount':'$srcRecCount'}""")
```

P.S. But really, do you really need that Scala piece? Why not to do everything in Python?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Could you please let me know how we do dbutils.notebook.exit in python.

Comment: The same way as in Scala - most of dbutils functions are available in Python under the same names

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible . Way Databricks has been configured,When you invoke a language magic command in cell , the command is dispatched to the REPL in the execution context for the notebook.Variables defined in that cell are not available in the REPL of another language/ another cell. REPLs can share state only through external resources such as files in DBFS or objects in object storage. In your case , You are trying to use magic command in both cells . This is expected behavioral . Hope this helps you to understand. Ref : https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#mix-languages. But still this is possible as workaround , you can write value in temp DBFS location and read it from there.